# card to cant added footer part

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Im used my university project for Ionic 3 and   try to do this image type [![Look at image][1]][1]

card, but its not work for me, i can put the header part but card footer part not working, anyone know how to do that correctly, i want to know how to create attached image type card,

my live [stackblitz live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yfc5wc)
please help me to fix it thanks,

**That is my code**

**html**

```
   <ion-grid>
      <!--Task 1st row-->
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4>
          <!--card-success-->
          <ion-card class="card-success">
          <ion-card-header>
            <p class="txt-rooms">Room 101</p>
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>

          </ion-card-content>

            <ion-row>


              <ion-col item-end>


                <ion-avatar item-end>
                  <img src="img/marty-avatar.png">
                </ion-avatar>

              </ion-col>

            </ion-row>
        </ion-card>
          <!--card-success-->
        </ion-col>



        <ion-col col-4>

          <!--card-warning-->
          <ion-card class="card-warning">
          <ion-card-header>
            <p class="txt-rooms">Room 102</p>
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>

          </ion-card-content>
            <ion-row>


              <ion-col item-end>


                <ion-avatar item-end>
                  <img src="img/marty-avatar.png">
                </ion-avatar>

              </ion-col>

            </ion-row>
        </ion-card>
          <!--card-warning-->

        </ion-col>


        <ion-col col-4>

          <!--card-info-->
          <ion-card class="card-info">
          <ion-card-header>
            <p class="txt-rooms">Room 103</p>
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>

          </ion-card-content>
            <ion-row>


              <ion-col item-end>


                <ion-avatar item-end>
                  <img src="img/marty-avatar.png">
                </ion-avatar>

              </ion-col>

            </ion-row>
        </ion-card>
          <!--card-info-->

        </ion-col>


      </ion-row>
      <!--Task 1st row-->
  </ion-grid>

**css**
```

.

```
card {
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 17vh;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
  }

  .card-md {
    margin: 0px;}
  .card-ios {
    margin: 0px;}


/*card-success*/
  .card-success.card {
    background: #fffae7;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 17vh;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
  }
  /*card-success*/


  /*card-warning*/
  .card-warning.card {
    background: #fff0ec;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 17vh;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
  }
  /*card-warning*/

  /*card-info*/
  .card-info.card {
    background: #edf5ff;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 17vh;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.2), 0 2px 4px rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
  }
  /*card-info*/
```

Comment: The footer works fine. Maybe the src of your image is wrong?

Comment: @Mystery Sir, Stack blitz live code to im not included image folder,my issue is im not correctly put the footer part ,look my attached  image i need like this

Comment: Yea, i know stackblitz but I also used your code to my sample project and used another image. Just modified the src path and it is working.

Comment: i changed and now Its work but images not a display inline any idea?

Comment: remove the`ion-avatar` and put your style to the `img`. like `border-radius` and `display`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I did the first card for you;)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bzaxt8

Use the ion-grid to place items the way you need.
Good guide here: https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-complex-layouts-in-ionic/

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for your valuable answered